# How is this defined?

Tags: c#, arrays

Is this an array of class property or a property class array?  And how do I access each row instead of each element in the class in C#? Thanks!

```
public partial class AdvancedSearchResult {

    private SearchResults[] searchResultsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    **[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SearchResults")]
    public SearchResults[] SearchResults { <-------NOT SURE HOW TO DEFINE THIS
        get {
            return this.searchResultsField;
        }
        set {
            this.searchResultsField = value;
        }
    }**


public partial class SearchResults {

    private int dIDField;

    private bool dIDFieldSpecified;

    private int dRevisionIDField;

    ...............etc
```

Comment: What do you want to define? The property is written correctly. Or do you want to assign a new value?

Comment: No the code is fine....I just don't understand how do I say this....is it a property of class arrays?  I think if I understand how this is defined I can understand how to access all the class members at once instead of each one, to fill in my listbox.

Comment: You've created a property (SearchResults) and field (searchResultsField) on your AdvancedSearchResult class.  That property is an array of SearchResults.  Upon declaration it'll point to null, because you haven't assigned a value to searchResultsField.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Your class should be called `SearchResult` and an array of `SearchResult` should be called `searchResults` and if it would be a property it would be `SearchResults`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** I understand you correctly:

1. Don't call your property `SearchResults` because that's the class's
   name. Call it `searchResults` .
2. Access a 'row' like this: `searchResults[rowNumber]`.

`searchResultsField` is an array, of which every member is a `SearchResults` class instance. And so is (de facto) your property. So it's **an array of class instances**.

To access a field in your property you would use `searchResults[rowNumber].fieldName` (assuming they were public fields).

**Due to your comment** - Here's a simple example of reflection:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass() { i = "a", j = "b" };
        FieldInfo[] infos = typeof(MyClass).GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo info in infos)
            Text += info.GetValue(myClass);
    }
}


class MyClass
{
    public string i;
    public string j;
}
```

And add at the top:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Comment: so if I wanted to add the data to a listbox I would need to concante each field name?  What if I had a hundred fields?  I tried adding it as a datasource and that did not work

Comment: @tawright915 That's usually how it's done. - One by one. However, if you had many fields and would want to iterate through them - you would do that using reflection.

Comment: I disagree about calling it searchResults.  Don't call your property searchResults just because the class is SearchResults.  Be consistent with your capitalization, and if all your other properties are pascal cased, keep that going.  
My preferred usage of capitalization: private + protected- camelCase.  Everything else- PascalCase.  all public methods and properties in the .NET runtime are also PascalCase, so it is nice to be consistent with them.

Comment: @sammy_winter My point wasn't preferring this or that. My point was that he is now hiding the class name with an _exact_ same name. He might then want to instantiate an instance using `SearchResults instance1 = new ...` only to find it doesn't work...

Comment: @tawright915 I updated my answer with an example of reflection. (And by the way, welcome to SO.)

Comment: @ispiro `SearchResults instance = new SearchResults();` will still work.  The compiler can tell the difference.  I agree that it's usually better not to use the class name as the variable name if there's a more descriptive name that will make more sense, but it will work without any difficulty as I don't think there are any cases where it would be ambiguous.

Comment: @sammy_winter just to put you at ease...I did not define that property as such.  It was an old WSDL that was sucked in and this is the proxy class that was created from it through VS.  I was just not sure how to describe this property or how to access all the fields within the array.  Thanks ispiro this helped alot.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would write your class a bit shorter:

```
public partial class AdvancedSearchResult 
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SearchResults")]
    public SearchResults[] SearchResults 
    {
        get 
        set 
    }
}
```

Second you can assign values:

```
AdvancedSearchResult results = new AdvancedSearchResult();
results.SearchResults = new[]
{
    new SearchResults { ... },
    new SearchResults { ... },
    etc.
}
```

To retrieve the values, you can use the index:

```
SearchResults firstResult = results.SearchResults[0];
```

Or use an enumerator:

```
foreach(SearchResults sr in results.SearchResults)
{
    // Something with sr.
}
```

Comment: I'm using the foreach statement now.  I just thought there was an easier way than:  sr.dIDField + sr.dIDFieldSpecified + sr.dRevisionIDField + etc and then adding that to a listbox with the add method.

Answer (score 0):

SearchResults is a property of class AdvancedSearchResult. It gets/sets the private array of SearchResults items called searchResultsField.

Access it as follows:

```
var result=new AdvancedSearchResult();

foreach(var item in result.SearchResults)
{  var myId= item.dIDField; 
   var isSpecified=item.dIDFieldSpecified;
   ...
}
```